# MVC4 Sending data from a text box in Controller to View using ActionLink and TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, tempdata

Is there a way to utilize TempData with a ActionLink to pass data from a View to a Controller. I have a View that has client-side validation and I need to update a drop down list from a text box on the page without using a submit button. When using two submit type buttons the client side validation flags all the fields that have not been filled in. Essentially I want to be able to add a user defined category to the drop down list without having to jump to a different view for just a textbox and submit button.

I was not sure if I could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="NewCat" value="@TempData["newCat"]" placeholder="New Catagory"/>
```

I couldn't quite get it to work though...

**The View:**

```
@model Exercise4.Models.Quote

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create New Quote</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Quotation Creation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatagoryID, "Catagory")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CatagoryID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatagoryID)
    </div>

    <aside>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("NewCatagory","Quote"))
        {
            <input type="text" name="NewCat" value="@TempData["newCat"]" placeholder="New Catagory"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Catagory","NewCatagory","Quote")

        }
    </aside>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QName)

    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QAuthor)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QAuthor)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QAuthor)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />

    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**The Controller Section:**

```
//
// Create New Catagory
public ActionResult NewCatagory()
{
    string value = TempData["newCat"] as string;
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        Catagory cat = new Catagory();
        cat.CatName = value;
        db.Catagories.Add(cat);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    ViewBag.CatagoryID = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "CatagoryID", "CatName");
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated either how to make this work or something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fix.

I rendered a partial view

Main View

```
<div class="asideRight">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        @Html.Partial("_AddCat", new Exercise4.Models.Category())
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Partial View

```
@model Exercise4.Models.Category

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("addCat", "Quote")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend class="myLegend">Create New Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CatName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input class="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="myValidation">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatName)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("")
    </div>
}
```

This allowed me to post back to the controller and add the new category before returning to the Create View

Controller Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult addCat(Category cat)
    {
        if (cat.CatName != null)
        {
            bool exists = db.Categories.Any(n => n.CatName.ToLower() == cat.CatName.ToLower());
            if (!exists)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(cat);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You entered a duplicate Category Name");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories.OrderBy(n => n.CatName), "CategoryID", "CatName");
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update data client-side, then use jQuery - especially if you don't need to go back to the server to get the data.  Use the element's click event to handle and manipulate your data client-side.  Something like

```
$("#addmore").on('click', function() {
    $("#someSelect").append('<option value="someoption">Some Option</option>');
});
```

Comment: This will only update the ddl locally and does not add it to the data base. It may be better to shut down the client side validation and submit the entire form for processing by the controller and redirect back before validating the model to add the quote. At least that is what I'm leaning towards.

Comment: in the function, you could also do an ajax post back to the server to update data.

Comment: Not that familar with ajax. Can you give me an example?